# How to print out the Multiplication table from 1 to 9, but skip all multiplications that are equal ?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have to print out The multiplication table like the displayed example:

[image: table]

This is what I have written so far :

```js
var a = 9;
var b = 9;

for (var x = 1; x <= a; x++){
    if (x > 1){    
        var y = 2;
        while (y <= b){
            var count = 0;
            count = x * y;
            process.stdout.write (x +" * "+ y +" = " + count+"; ");
            y++;
        }
        console.log();
  
    } else {
        var y = 1;
        while (y <= b){
            var count = 0;
            count = x * y;
            process.stdout.write (x +" * "+ y +" = " + count+"; ");
            y++;
        }
        console.log();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I see no question in here. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) to know how to ask a good and relevant question. Edit your question to increase its quality.

Comment: It's printing out this : https://prnt.sc/hhpim6 , and I want to skip  all the
Multiplications that are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that it's better to store the multiplication facts you're generating (such as `"3 * 7 = 21"`) in a data structure, and then output them however you like.  There are other possibilities, but the simplest one is probably an array of arrays of Strings.  So starting with a `range` function that does, for instance, `range(3, 7) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, you could write the code like this:

```
const multTable = (a, b) => range(1, Math.min(a, b)).map(
  x => range(x + 1, Math.max(a, b)).map(y => `${x} * ${y} = ${x * y}`)
)
```

Then `multTable(9, 9)` would give such a data structure, which you could log like this:

```
console.log(multTable(9, 9).map(row => row.join('; ')).join('\n'))
```

Or you could alternately choose to format it in HTML, or do something else with it entirely.

```js
// range :: (Int, Int) -> [Int]
// Ex: range(3, 7) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const range = (start, end) => Array(end + 1 - start).fill(0).map((_, i) => i + start)

// range :: (Int, Int) -> [[MultiplicationFact]]
// where a MultiplicationFact is a string such as '3 * 7 = 21'
const multTable = (a, b) => range(1, Math.min(a, b)).map(
  x => range(x + 1, Math.max(a, b)).map(y => `${x} * ${y} = ${x * y}`)
)

console.log(multTable(9, 9).map(row => row.join('; ')).join('\n'))
```

Or, if you decided that this was the only format you could possibly need, then you could alter the function easily to generate it directly:

```
const multTable = (a, b) => range(1, Math.min(a, b)).map(
  x => range(x + 1, Math.max(a, b)).map(y => `${x} * ${y} = ${x * y}`).join('; ')
).join('\n')
```

And use it more simply with:

```
console.log(multTable(5, 7))
```

```js
// range :: (Int, Int) -> [Int]
// Ex: range(3, 7) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
const range = (start, end) => Array(end + 1 - start).fill(0).map((_, i) => i + start)

// range :: (Int, Int) -> [[MultiplicationFact]]
// where a MultiplicationFact is a string such as '3 * 7 = 21'
const multTable = (a, b) => range(1, Math.min(a, b)).map(
  x => range(x + 1, Math.max(a, b)).map(y => `${x} * ${y} = ${x * y}`).join('; ')
).join('\n')

console.log(multTable(5, 7))
```

Note that depending upon what you're doing, you might want a more sophisticated data structure.  Instead of `"3 * 7 = 21"`, there are times when this would be better: `{multiplicands: [3, 7], product: 21}`, but often that would be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Multiply</title>
  <script>
    function multiply() {
      for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        let val = '';
        for (let j = i; j <= 9; j++) {
          val += `${i} * ${j} = ${i * j}; `;
        }
        console.log(val);
      }
    }

    window.onload = multiply();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ! :) @assembler

Answer (score 1):

In the exemple we can see that for each x the multiplication start with y == x.

So you simply need to start the second loop with y = x

```
var a = 9;
var b = 9;

for (var x = 1; x <= a; x++){
    for (var y = x; y <= b; y++) {
        var count = 0;
        count = x * y;
        process.stdout.write (x +" * "+ y +" = " + count+"; ");
    }
    console.log(); 
}
```

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about that. Thanks a lot ! :) @Techniv